# SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
The problem is in (bot). This part of the code:

```js
let task = async (bot) => {
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please read first a tutorial about async/await: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async functions are not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6.

You'll need to transpile your code (e.g. using Babel) to a version of JS that Node understands if you are using an older version.